# Postgres case insensitive searching with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, case-insensitive, sql-like

My development database is SQLite but I deploy my app to Heroku and they are using PostgreSQL.

Now sometimes I have two different results coming out if I perform searches because PostgreSQL is case-sensitive but SQLite is not.

Shouldn't Rails standardize these things? What methods should I use to solve that?

[Here is how to fix it with raw SQL](http://www.devdaily.com/blog/post/postgresql/do-case-insensitive-searching-with-postgresql)

Comment: I'd recommend developing on top of PostgreSQL if you're deploying to Heroku. No ORM will protect you from database-specific behavior.

Comment: And I like using SQLite locally and Postgre on shipping, so I'm not tied to an certain DB. to each his own.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Case insensitive searching in Postgres:

- use `ilike` instead of `like` (case-insensitive like)
- if you want to use =, make both sides either UPPER or LOWER

Comment: Thank you! The problem with `like` is that i don't know how to chain them with the `OR` operator. Is it save to use this with every supported db by rails? `"LOWER(title) LIKE LOWER('%#{search_term}%')"`

Comment: well it doesnt brake my code in mysql, sqlite and pgsql so its good enough, thanks!

Comment: use UPPER or LOWER if you want to run the same code on both MYSQL and POSTGRES (although that is obviously not best practice!)

Answer (score 4):

Another `DDL` way of handling this is the [`citext`](http://pgfoundry.org/projects/citext) data type, or case-insensitive TEXT.

Answer (score 4):

There are many relatively common things that ActiveRecord doesn't handle, and LIKE matching is one of them. Here is how to achieve this using straight Arel instead.

```
Model.where(
  Model.arel_table[:title].matches("%#{search_term}%")
)
```

You can install [Arel-Helpers](https://github.com/camertron/arel-helpers) to make this a little easier

```
Model.where(Model[:title].matches("%#{search_term}%"))
```

I previously recommended [Squeel](https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/squeel) for this, but the original creator has stopped supporting it and there doesn't seem to be a full-time developer maintaining it. And since it plays around with private ActiveRecord APIs, it needs constant tending.

Comment: Great solution, and Squeel is awesome, but just a heads up that this is Postgres-specific behavior. If you are looking to do this for other RDBMS the output may be case sensitive.

Comment: @kgx actually this example will work as intended in both cases. As @antpaw says above, SQLite `LIKE` is case-insensitive by default. So this will use `LIKE` in SQLite and `ILIKE` in PostgreSQL.